# shorten svc file name for publishing

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, naming, svc

I have a punch of wcf service, the point here that when i publish them the svc file name start to be the same with  the service behavior class and name space, so if the class is 
`BBServices.BBBO.Caching.B`BCacheClientService
the svc name is BBServices.BBBO.Caching.BBCacheClientService.svc
how i can shorten the name of the svc file to be BBCacheClientService.svc.

Answer (score 2):

i found it out;
set the ConfigurationName in the servicebehavior attribute to the name wanted and change the
the service name in the config to the same name.